# When creating an object from a class, to set a different default value for only the first object created?

Tags: java, scope

I am trying to create the first account with a large balance, and all remaining with a default balance of zero. Thanks!

```
public class Account {
    String address;
    int balance;
    public HashMap<String,Integer> AccountBalanceMap = new HashMap<>();
    boolean firstOnly = true;

public Account(String address) {

    this.address = address;
    this.balance = 0;

    if(firstOnly) {
        AccountBalanceMap.put(address, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        firstOnly == false;
        System.out.println("first ran");
    } else {
        AccountBalanceMap.put(address, 0);
        System.out.println("second+ ran");
    }
    System.out.println(AccountBalanceMap);
}
```

}

Comment: That would need to be in a static (class) variable, not an instance variable, which is created per-instance. IMO, though, this logic doesn't belong in the account, rather in whatever is creating the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static member.
e.g.

```
static int nextBalance = 1000;
public Account(String address) {
    this.balance = nextBalance;
    nextBalance = 0;
```